# selenium ios-driver C#

Tags: c#, ios, selenium

i am trying the new selenium [ios-driver](http://freynaud.github.io/ios-driver/) . i have a hybrid app which would like to test especially the following code

```
 DesiredCapabilities cap = IOSCapabilities.iphone("InternationalMountains", "1.1");
```

However, it appears the code on this web site is JAVA.

Can we use C# selenium API to use with ios-driver? I try to call

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://www:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.IPhone());
```

Does it provide any way to start the app and use C# selenium API to test?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the Appium Server to receive the connection?

Appium is both a WebDriver that can interact with a device in your project as well as a Server that bridges your project to your physical device or emulator.

You have to run the Appium server as a listener and set up your Capabilities to connect to it. That will start the app and execute your test.

There is a lot more to it than this but here is a setup that you can try to get you on your way:

In a WebDriver Support Class use the [BeforeScenario] tag to execute this code before your test. This has a Sauce Labs implementation.

```
[BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        var name = Locale == "sauce" ? "AppiumSauceDriver" : "AppiumDriver";
        InitializeServiceLocator();
        if (WebDriver == null)
        {
            InitializeWebDriver(name);
        }

        ObjectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(WebDriver);

        if (WebDriver != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Driver Already Exists");
        }
    }
```

Then you need to populate the InitializeServiceLocator() method. There is a Device Selector Method here that doesn't do anything other than set the name. You can just hard code it to your capabilities instead.

```
private static void InitializeServiceLocator()
    {
        if (ServiceLocator == null)
        {
            var ip = "";
            var deviceType = TestSetupHelper.DeviceSelector["iphone7"];
            var capabilities = TestSetupHelper.SetAppiumCababilities(deviceType, Locale);
            string server = MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("appiumServer");
            var port = Convert.ToInt32(MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("appiumPort"));
            if (Locale != "sauce")
            {
                ip = TestSetupHelper.GetComputerIpAddress(server, port, true);
            }

            var kernel = new StandardKernel();

            kernel.Bind<IOSDriver<AppiumWebElement>>().ToConstructor(x => new IOSDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://" + ip + ":" + port + "/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))).Named("AppiumDriver");
            kernel.Bind<IOSDriver<AppiumWebElement>>().ToConstructor(x => new IOSDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))).Named("AppiumSauceDriver");

            ServiceLocator = new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel);
            Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => ServiceLocator);
        }
    }
```

From here you need to set up your capabilities. The below method is how I have done it.

```
 public static DesiredCapabilities SetAppiumCababilities(string deviceType, string locale, bool realDevice = false, string udid = "FAKEUDIDFOREXAMPLE")
    {
        string appiumAppFilePath = MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("appiumAppFilePath");

        //Universal Capabilities
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", deviceType);
        capabilities.SetCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
        capabilities.SetCapability("app", appiumAppFilePath);
        capabilities.SetCapability("xcodeOrgId", "GET_THIS_FROM_APP_DEV");
        capabilities.SetCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
        capabilities.SetCapability("noReset", true);
        capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", 80);

        if (locale == "sauce")//Sauce specific capabilities
        {
            capabilities.SetCapability("appiumVersion", "1.7.2");
            capabilities.SetCapability("name", MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("appiumJobName"));
            capabilities.SetCapability("username", MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("sauceId"));
            capabilities.SetCapability("accessKey", MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("sauceKey"));
            capabilities.SetCapability("tunnel-identifier", MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("sauceTunnel"));
            capabilities.SetCapability("browserName", "");
            capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "11.2");
        }
        else//Local specific capabilities
        {
            capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "11.3");
        }

        if (realDevice)//Sauce real device testing will not need this. This is for Local Real Device testing only
        {
            capabilities.SetCapability("udid", udid);
        }

        return capabilities;
    }
```

Anything referencing GetRunParameter is getting a value from a .runsettings file.

Example:

```
<TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="appiumJobName" value="OBI App Automated Test"/>
</TestRunParameters>
```

You have to add all of the stuff to the .runsettings file you are using to run the project that you want to source from there. You can hardcode it if you don't want to go through the runsettings file but I prefer to do it that way. You can make things variable that way based on the runsettings file you have selected.

Then you have to define TestSetupHelper.GetComputerIpAddress(server, port, true);
If you have a hard coded IP Address to the computer that is running your Appium server you can just hard code that. Otherwise you need a Helper class somewhere (In this example it is TestSetupHelper). This example initiates a Socket Connection to the server and returns all of the details. That way you don't have to worry about IP addresses changing. You just pass the host name and the port you have Appium configured to run on and you can get the connection information from that connection and make your actual connection to the Appium Server instance.

```
public static string GetComputerIpAddress(string computerName, int port, bool remote)
    {
        var ip = "";
        using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 0))
        {
            socket.Connect(computerName, port);
            //If remote it gets the connection destination IP, else it gets the connection initiator IP
            IPEndPoint endPoint = remote ? socket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint : socket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
            ip = endPoint.Address.ToString();
        }

        return ip;
    }
```

This isn't going to get you completely there but it will get you close to a working environment. Then you can start working on getting a test to actually run.

I hope this helps.

J.R.